# Is there any way to get ActiveMQ queue current pending messages count

Tags: node.js, activemq-classic, stomp

Currently I am using I am using ActiveMQ 5.15.12 and the `stompit` module in Node.js. Queue subscription and processing of message received is all working fine.

I am looking for an option to find the count of current pending messages in the queue, and I need to use Node.js to do it.

Comment: Sorry @justin I need via node.js

Comment: apache-activemq-5.15.12

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`node-jmx`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jmx). It should allow you to query [ActiveMQ's MBeans](https://activemq.apache.org/jmx.html). The queue's MBean name follows this pattern:

```
type=Broker,brokerName=<name-of-broker>,destinationType=Queue,destinationName=<name>
```

The attribute you want to inspect is `QueueSize`.